# Getting BadRequestException in JUnit using Mockito

Tags: junit, java-8, mockito, spring-webflux

I'm writing a Junit for a service class using Mockito. Application has been built up using Java 8, Spring 5. While my rest of test methods are running fine except this one where I'm stuck and unable to proceed further.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = CommerceConnectorApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class CommerceRepositoryDetailsTest {

  @Autowired
  private RepositoryDetails repositoryDetails;

  @MockBean
  private AsyncRunner asyncRunner;

  @MockBean
  private CommerceTenantUserRepository tenantUserRepository;

  @Test
  public void whenUpdateCartId_ThenReturnUpdatedTenantUserDetails(){
    String tenantId = "2737363";
    String userId = "763sssj";
    String cartId = "827";

    TenantUserKey tenantUserKey = new TenantUserKey();
    tenantUserKey.setTenantId(tenantId);
    tenantUserKey.setUserId(userId);

    CommerceTenantUser commerceTenantUser = new CommerceTenantUser(tenantUserKey, "xyz@abc.com", cartId, LocalDate.now());
    Optional <CommerceTenantUser> commerceTenantUser1 = Optional.of(commerceTenantUser);


    Mockito.when(tenantUserRepository.findById(tenantUserKey)).thenReturn(commerceTenantUser1);

    Mono<CommerceTenantUser> actualMono = repositoryDetails.updateCartId(tenantId, userId, cartId);
    CommerceTenantUser commerceTenantUser2 = actualMono.block();

    assertThat(commerceTenantUser2, is(commerceTenantUser));

  }
}
```

Error :-

```
2018-08-14 16:19:38.843  INFO 106888 --- [           main] c.s.c.c.c.s.CommerceRepositoryDetails    : Entering updateCartId@CommerceSystemDetailService

com.sap.chatbot.commerceconnector.exception.BadRequestException: error in updating cart

    at com.sap.chatbot.commerceconnector.common.security.CommerceRepositoryDetails.updateCartId(CommerceRepositoryDetails.java:139)
    at com.sap.chatbot.commerceconnector.common.security.CommerceRepositoryDetails$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fd3bfefe.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:337)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.sap.chatbot.commerceconnector.common.security.CommerceRepositoryDetails$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b388d4d.updateCartId(<generated>)
    at com.sap.chatbot.commerceconnector.CommerceRepositoryDetailsTest.whenUpdateCartId_ThenReturnUpdatedTenantUserDetails(CommerceRepositoryDetailsTest.java:124)
```

The main method to test :-

```
    @Override
    @CachePut(value = CommerceConnectorConstants.CommerceCache.COMMERCE_CACHE_TENANT_USER_DATA_MAP)
    public Mono<CommerceTenantUser> updateCartId(String tenantId, String userId, String cartId) {
        logger.info("Entering updateCartId@CommerceSystemDetailService");

        final TenantUserKey commerce = getTenantUserObj(tenantId, userId);
        Optional<CommerceTenantUser> tenantUser = commerceTenantUserRepository.findById(commerce);

        return tenantUser.map(tenantUserObj -> updateCartIdAndRefreshMap(tenantUserObj, cartId))
                .orElse(Mono.error(new BadRequestException("error in updating cart")));

    }

    private Mono<CommerceTenantUser> updateCartIdAndRefreshMap(CommerceTenantUser tenantUserObj, String cartId) {
        tenantUserObj.setCartId(cartId);
        final Mono<CommerceTenantUser> commerceTenantUser = asyncRunner
                .one(() -> commerceTenantUserRepository.saveAndFlush(tenantUserObj))
                .doOnNext(value -> commerceCacheService.refreshMap())
                .doOnError(error -> Mono.error(new BadRequestException("Error ocurred in updating cart id ")))
                .map(commerceTenantUserObj -> commerceTenantUserObj);
        return commerceTenantUser;

    }
```

The method **updateCartId()** calls another private method **updateCartIdAndRefreshMap()**. My JUnit fails in return statment in **updateCartId()**.

Please advise on how to fix my JUnit to test this specific updateCartId() method.

Comment: You're mocking asynchRunner, but there are no when calls against it.

Comment: Hi @MichaelPeacock, I'm sorry, I did not understand by your statement 'but there are no when calls against it...'. Yes, I'm mocking asynchRunner because the private method updateCartIdAndRefreshMap() required it. Can you please elaborate your statement so that I can understand you? Thank you

Comment: The asynchRunner object is a mock object. You make several calls to this mock in updateCartIdAndRefreshMap(), yet there are no Mockito.when(asynchRunner.xxx() ... ) calls in your test.